# Copy last row on change - simultaneous entries

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google script that copies the last row on that spreadsheet to another spreadsheet sheet every time an entry is made. This entry is not linked to a Google form at all - so it is not bound to an onFormSubmit trigger - this submission is made from a JotForm form and inserted into the spreadsheet automatically. What I would like to know if my code will always work even if say two users make their submissions at the same time.

The code works fine - there seems to be no problem with that. I use the On change trigger. But I'd like to make sure it would always work. Many thanks for your help in advance.

```
function copyLastRow() {
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx').getSheetByName('Records');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var sourceData = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1, 1, 10).getValues();
 target.appendRow(sourceData[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of the template I imagine you could use in completing this objective.

```
function updateSpreadsheet() {

  //Open Form Responses Spreadsheet and get the Sheet you are reading data from
  // You will need to update ID and SheetName parameters for your own sheets.
  var formResponses = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheetByName(SheetName);

  //Open destinationSheet that you are writing to and get the sheet that you are writing to
  // You will need to update ID and SheetName parameters for your own sheets.
  var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheetByName(SheetName);

  //Getting last rows from formResponse and destinationSheet
  //It is not totally necessary to create everything as a variable, but I wanted to make it explicit what I am doing here
  var formResponsesLastRow = formResponses.getLastRow();
  var destinationSheetLastRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow();

  //We are going to calculate the difference between the formResponse and destinationSheet 
  //This lets us know how many more rows have been added since we last updated destinationSheet
  var numberNewRows = formResponsesLastRow - destinationSheetLastRow;


  //Now get the new data to Write  
  var dataToWrite = formResponses.getRange((formResponsesLastRow - numberNewRows) + 1 , 1, numberNewRows, 3).getValues();

  //Write to destinationSheet
  destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheetLastRow + 1, 1, numberNewRows, 3).setValues(dataToWrite);



}
```

Comment: I need to clarify my question: I am not concerned about the actual submissions to the original sheet. I am concerned about the script that copies the last row to the second spreadsheet. So if two submissions are made at the same time, these will create two last rows. I need to make sure that each row will be copied to the destinations sheet - is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Got it.  Two is arbitrary and it could be 3 or 4 additional to submissions n-1 of which you will miss because you're only looking for the last row.  I would take the extra step to compare the length of each data sets (destination and form responses) to determine how many new rows need to be added.  Does this effectively describe your problem?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. But I am a very inexperienced coder and I wouldn't know what steps I should take. Will you be able to help?

Comment: I forgot to add that I had a similar question that was tied to the onFormSubmit trigger which was solved with using the Google Sheet Events - but it probably wouldn't work with the onChange trigger.

Comment: I updated my response above with a template you should be able use.  It does a quick calculation to understand the differences in shapes between the two sheets LastRows() and then gets/sets values based upon that.  If you have some unique identifier that would only be generated once (maybe the timestamp?) then we could use logic to make sure the data is exactly new and not just based upon the shape.

Comment: Great. Yes, I do have the Timestamp. Could this be used?

Comment: Sure.  You could use the Timestamp. If you have another unique identifier or something where the combination of it + the Timestamp is unlikely to be duplicated in your responses, then that would even be better.

Comment: I wanted to upvote your answer but I am not allowed to as I don't have enough reputations. If you could bear with me, how should I use the Timestamp in the code you provided? Many thanks.